# Breaking the discrete logarithm problem in subgroups of $G$

Tags: discrete-logarithm

I need to find the discrete logarithm of 20 modulo 71 where the generator of the group is 7. I need to break the group $|G|=2 \times 5 \times 7$ in subgroups $|G_1|=2, |G_2|=5, |G_3|=7$. I am new to this. Can someone please help me out?

Edit:
Till now, I have reduced the above problem to the following system of equations (I don't know if I'm correct.):

\begin{align}
20^{35}&=(7^{35})^a\text{ in }G_1\\20^{14}&=(7^{14})^a\text{ in }G_2\\20^{10}&=(7^{10})^a\text{ in }G_3
\end{align}

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Since this is homework, look at [this](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/56264)

Comment: What have you tried?  Does the name Pohlig–Hellman mean anything to you?

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage No it doesn't.

Comment: @kelalaka Thank you. And it isn't homework but it was asked in the quiz.

Comment: You can post your solution.